# .NET Core Api slow response

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

Yesterday I figured, that the WebAPI I published is not very fast. Usually every request takes round about 300 ms in a *local* environment (Release mode).
To make sure my own code was not the problem I created a new Web Application in Visual Studio 2017 and picked "WebAPI" project. When I start the fresh project in release mode and request the values controller, that only returns ["value1","value2"], I get response times fluctuating between 50 and 100ms.
If I create a new WebAPI .NET Core Project I get a worse result: Values between 100 and 200 ms.
For me those are very bad results for a local environment and with getting this small amount of data.

If you create a fresh project - are response times:

- Faster?
- More stable (not fluctuating between 100 or 200ms)?

And are there any proposals what I could try to speed up my API. I can not believe that it sometimes takes 200 ms to request literally less than a kilobyte.

I mean: Even this online API is a lot faster and returns more data: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts (ca. 20 ms)

Comment: When you say local environment, do you mean your machine?

Comment: Yes, and it does not matter if I run IIS Express or in case of .NET Core directly as a console application. If I publish the sample app to our server it needs the same time.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you running? I have just tried my .NET Core 1.0 app hosted by Kestrel on localhost which returns about 185KB of data from in-memory cache. It took 28ms (measured by Chrome Developer Tools) or 18ms (measured by .NET Core app itself in logs) to process the request.

Comment: Wow! You have so much better results. I run version 1.1, but also tried 1.0 and Web API 2. All not faster than 100ms.

Comment: This sounds *potentially* more like a hardware issue. Have you tried running a new Core project on a different machine?

Comment: I do not think it has to do with the code neither. My hardware is quiet fast, but I will try on another machine and give feedback. My guess is, that it has to do with the webserver.

Comment: How exactly are you running the code? How are you measuring the response time?